# multiplication of 3-dimensional matrix in numpy

Tags: python, matrix, numpy, matrix-multiplication

I think I asked the [wrong question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15516801/1382745) yesterday. What I actually want is to mutiply two `2x2xN` matrices `A` and `B`, so that

```
C[:,:,i] = dot(A[:,:,i], B[:,:,i])
```

For example, if I have a matrix

```
A = np.arange(12).reshape(2, 2, 3)
```

How can I get `C = A x A` with the definition described above? Is there a built-in function to do this?

---

Also, if I multiply `A (shape 2x2xN)` with `B (shape 2x2x1, instead of N)`, I want to get

```
C[:,:,i] = dot(A[:,:,i], B[:,:,1])
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using `numpy.einsum`, it has a little bit of a learning curve but it should give you what you want. Here is an example to get you started.

```
import numpy as np

A = np.random.random((2, 2, 3))
B = np.random.random((2, 2, 3))

C1 = np.empty((2, 2, 3))
for i in range(3):
    C1[:, :, i] = np.dot(A[:, :, i], B[:, :, i])

C2 = np.einsum('ijn,jkn->ikn', A, B)
np.allclose(C1, C2)
```

Comment: This is amazing. It works for both cases in the question. It even works when I swap `A` and `B` (of different shape, in second question).

Comment: +1 The first time I saw `einsum` used, it had that ["undistinguishable from magic"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clarke's_three_laws) flavor, great function, and superfast.

Comment: @Bi Rico, @Jaime, ok, aside the awesomeness, can someone explain a little about what's going on with `'ijn,jkn->ikn'`? I found it hard to relate the numpy document to this particular case.

Comment: @LWZ First, you need to understand that a matrix dot product would be written as `('ij,jk->ik')` (see http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MatrixMultiplication.html). Then, you want to do the same thing for all matrices in the last dimension, which is what adding `n` at the end does. Maybe it can help you to see it more clearly if you replace the looping variable in the answer above from `i` to `n`.

Comment: @jorgeca Thanks you! Now I understand that part. But for the last part of my question, when the last dimension of the two input are different, `N` vs `1`, why does it also work? Wouldn't it cause confusion what's the last dimension of the output?

Comment: @LWZ That's a really interesting issue. I don't know why it still works. If we had written `('ij...,jk...->ik...')` I wouldn't be surprised that it also worked, though.

Comment: The reason it works when the last dimension is different is because numpy broadcasts, http://www.scipy.org/EricsBroadcastingDoc, the arrays to have compatible shapes. Here is the error message you get when the last dimensions are 3 and 4: `ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with remapped shapes [original->remapped]: (2,2,3)->(2,newaxis,3,2) (2,2,4)->(2,4,2)`.

Comment: But `einsum` does not allow broadcasting unless you add an ellipsis (`...`). The docs clearly say `einsum does not allow broadcasting by default. To enable and control broadcasting, use an ellipsis.` Is that wrong or is there a bug?